# How to create a proxy server to bypass IP whitelist

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, whitelist

We have an apache server is running in server A.
We have an webservice is running in server B which is enable IP whitelist. So only server A can use request to web service.

I am using browser in machine C which only able to access to server B. How can I create a proxy server in A so that become a middle man that allow machine C can access the webservice in B.

Comment: I would really like to know this as well